# How to create plain text flashcards for the Kindle?

Tags: kindle, calibre, editing, creation, send-to-kindle

Amazon **for the Mac** can create flashcards:

```
Amazon Device Support › Kindle for Mac › Read Books› 


Read with Flashcards

Flashcards are note cards created for select content on Kindle for Mac, which include a word and definition. You can use them to test your memory of key terms and concepts. 


• Access Flashcards: ◦ While reading, click on the Flashcards  icon, located on the left side of the screen. 

• Create Flashcards Decks: ◦ While reading click on the X-Ray  or Notebook  icon, and select the Export to Flashcards  icon. Add a name for the Flashcards Deck and click OK to create a new entry. 
◦ While reading click on the Flashcards  icon and click on the plus icon at the top to create a new deck. 

• Edit Flashcards: ◦ Click on Edit Deck at the lower right corner of the screen, select a section and make your changes, and then select Done. Click on Flip Sides to reverse the order of the information on your Flashcard. 
◦ To delete a Flashcard, click on Edit Deck and then click on Delete Card and select OK. 

• Use Flashcards ◦ While reading, click on the Flashcard  icon and then select the set you want to use. Click on a card to read the other side. 
◦ To shuffle your set, click on the Shuffle icon. 
◦ To restart your set, click on the Refresh icon.
```

But how can I do something like that from Windows or Linux?  Perhaps even typing in manually on the Kindle itself...

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Windows now has this feature.

For a nicely detailed look, see:
 https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-kindle-app-windows-read-ebooks?page=1